# A linux program/script for keeping certain folders below fixed size, removing oldest files if neccessary?

Tags: linux, directory, disk-space-utilization

E.g. the [autotrash](http://www.logfish.net/pr/autotrash/) would do perfectly if it wasn't bound to monitor trash folders only.

Comment: This question seems valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `autotrash` and tell it which directory to keep in shape by telling it that directory is the trash with the `-T` option? Just because it's called a" trash" directory doesn't mean you have to use it only on directories that GNOME thinks are trash directories...

Comment: Because by «bound to monitor trash folders only» I meant exactly that.
    

    `# autotrash --dry-run --delete=102400 --max-free=102400 -T /mydir
    Can not find trash information directory. Make sure you have at least GNOME 2.24
    I was looking at: /mydir/info`

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively easy to write such an application:
- When it initializes put an inotify hook on the folder to see what changes inside it and on all existing files.
- Initialize a queue of files (basically read them sorted by creation or modification date and add them to the queue).
- Whenever a file is created/modified/etc, make the necessary action (move it to the end of the queue, delete the first one etc).